# SQLite storing, retrieving and comparing a DATETIME field

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, datetime, comparison

I am really stuck trying to compare dates in SQLite queries in Objective C. Here's what I'm doing:

**Storing the date:**

[This document](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) tells me to use the dateformat specified below, but it doesn't seem right. I tried using `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` without success too though.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO user (edited) VALUES (\"%@\")", dateString];
```

**Comparing the date**

I am using a timestamp for this, which I convert to a datetime string

```
long stamp = [sessie integerForKey:@"stamp"];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:stamp]];

sqlite3_stmt *result = [db selectQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM user WHERE edited > '%@'", dateString]];
```

The timestamp is simply generated using `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]`. The problem is that the query won't give the correct results, and I don't even know if the date is stored correctly in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated, but I assume you're aware that you should be wary about using `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL. It's ok in this scenario, but if ever using any user input, you should use `?` placeholder with `sqlite3_bind_text` or else you expose yourself to a bunch of issues. Doing `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions properly can be cumbersome, but using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) can also make your life much easier when interfacing with your database (and it completely solves your date related questions, too).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. And I will certainly checkout FMDB. I'm learning a lot today :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. For your date string, you do definitely do not want to use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. That will not generate a valid date string. Using `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` is much closer, but not quite right, either (since you'll use 12-hour `hh`). Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead.
2. This date format, though, does not capture time zone, so, if you store date strings in your SQLite database, you should use UTC (GMT) as discussed in the SQLite [Date And Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) documentation.

   ```
   NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
   formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
   formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
   NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
   ```

   As shown above, you probably want to also specify the `locale` so that the format of the dates will not change depending upon the localization settings of the device.
3. Note that you might consider using `timeIntervalSince1970` to store the date as a `REAL` value in your database (as opposed to a `TEXT`). This can be a little more efficient and automatically addresses the UTC issue.

Comment: The comparison using timestamps like you suggested works like a charm. Thanks for the hints on using date formats as well, very instructive!