# How to save date in sqlite tables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I can save DATE with core data and all operation is working fine.

I can not save DATE as string as my fetch request will have filters on a DATE column.

Sqlite has a support of DateTime datatype but unfortunately, I can't save my IOS current dateTime. Any Suggestion?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115571/sqlite-storing-retrieving-and-comparing-a-datetime-field

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302664/objective-c-and-sqlites-datetime-type

Comment: can you be more specific to why you can't save current `dateTime` ? Some code snippets maybe?

Comment: Above link will not help me as I can't save the date as a string. Sorry.

Comment: @yStack, with my insert query I'm trying to save Date as blob and some other type but is setting null...

Comment: see this https://behestee.com/2011/08/18/objective-c-and-sqlites-datetime-type/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, the above link is not what I want... they are converting it to a string. So with string, I can not apply date operations.

Comment: I need something like sqlite3_bind_int64 which can save DateTime or timestamp. Hope this makes clear. Thanks

Comment: you need to convert again string to nsdate

Comment: If I convert it to a string then we won't be able to apply date comparison condition by expecting it will do an operation on a date as it will consider it as a string.
Anyway thank you for all your support. I will update here once I do it

Answer (score 0):

Convert the NSDate into a string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:actualYearDate];
NSString *stringFromDate = [NSString stringFromDate:date];
```

And you can use this string. [Date format](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdateformatter) you can choose as you want.